# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5.8

I want to show category and paent_id. but I tried for it but I did not successfully.

category.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="parent_id">Category</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="parent_id" name="parent_id">
        <option value="">{{ $categories }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CategoryController.php

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::getCatList();
    return view('Admin.categories.create', compact('categories'));
}
```

Category.php

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'parent_id'];

public static function getCatList ()
{
    $array = array();
    $array[0] = 'Main Category';
    $category = self::with('getChild')->where('parent_id', 0)->get();
    foreach ($category as $key => $value) {
        $array[$value->id] = $value->name;
    }
    return $array;
}

public function getChild ()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

I see this error...

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\new\shopping\resources\views\Admin\categories\create.blade.php)

Comment: You can't use an array in `{{ }}`, so `{{ $categories }}` is invalid. You need to use a loop.

Comment: What's the solution?

Comment: "You need to use a loop." Is there something unclear about that? Loop over your `$categories` variable and create an `<option>` for each.

Comment: @foreach($categories as $category)
      <option value="">{{ $category->name }}</option>
     @endforeach
it IS ERROR

>  Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\new\shopping\resources\views\Admin\categories\create.blade.php)

Comment: Then `$category` is not an object. Your code suggests that it's the result of `$value->name;`, so probably just `{{ $category }}`, and not `{{ $category->name }}`

Comment: Can you send complete code??? that how to create category with parents

Comment: I just did! Use `{{ $category }}` instead of `{{ $category->name }}` ...

Comment: but when i add a category I see this error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'parent_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `categories` (`name`, `parent_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (یننی, ?, 2019-05-21 21:57:28, 2019-05-21 21:57:28))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't use an array in `.blade` without a loop, so `{{ $categories }}` is invalid. Use a loop:

```
@foreach($categories AS $category)
  <option value ...>
@endforeach
```

Next, you need to pass something to use a value, and something to use as a label. They way you have it now, you're only passing `$value->name`, refactor to:

```
$categories = self::with('getChild')->where('parent_id', 0)->get();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $array[$category->id] = $category;
}
```

Then, in your view, you can access `$category->id` and `$category->name` in each of your `option>`s:

```
@foreach($categories AS $category)
  <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Previous, you could have done it like so: (if you keep your code as `$array[$value->id] = $value->name;`)

```
@foreach($categories AS $id => $name)
  <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Either way is fine.